# Types are not highlighted their usual green in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

I am familiar with previous versions of Visual Studio, and the new Express Edition (that is, Desktop Express 2012) is missing some of the familiar highlighting procedures.

After having the problem and following the instructions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988077/plain-c-sharp-editor-in-visual-studio-2012-no-intellisense-no-indentation-no), I have succeeded in restoring intellisense, automatic indentation, and blue-colored keywords, but the classes, structs, and other types are no longer highlighted their familiar green color.

The question is, can I get this familiar green type highlighting back, or is it intentionally omitted in Visual Studio Desktop Express 2012?

Comment: This is, of course, a purely aesthetic question, but the lack of green highlighting bothers me for no good reason.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Visual Studio 2012 Code Highlighting for structs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14253879/855050)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your Font and Colors settings(Tools->Environment->Fonts and colors) in Visual studio for User Types.