# Syntax highlight fail on Classes in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

I recently installed Visual Studio on a laptop and the syntax highlight fails to change Classes colors.

I tried exporting and importing the full, complete set of settings and it is still looking like that.

**EDIT**

I tried those websites with schemes and decided to try one, the Humane scheme, and this is how the sample code looks in my laptop after installing those settings:

[image]

However, this is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

Note the lack of highlight in class names.

What could it be causing this?
I'm starting to think that's another setting at another place which causes this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, it worked by resetting user data, running this from the Visual Studio Command Prompt

```
devenv /Resetuserdata
```

Found the hint here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988265/1213246

Comment: This worked, but it is a pretty radical step.  I lost all my extensions, syntax highlighting, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Changin syntax highlight could be done through the menu `Tools - Options - Environment - Font & Colors`. It's a try and test approach that is not much improved from earlier versions of Visual Studio.

Fortunately, today there are entire sites with themes that simply need to be choosen and installed
I suggest you to visit http://studiostyl.es/ where you can find thousands themes or, for more generic go to http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know I can change it that way, but why they were setup different to start with? I'm using same installation disk, same settings.

Comment: Do you have any add-ins that mess with colors?

Comment: The only 3rd party tool I use is DevExpress, but it is also installed in my PC, in which the other settings are ok. Besides that I checked your link and I see those style schemes are simply .settings files, but I have also tried export and import, choosing the full settings unless there is an special place to import/export syntax highlight.

Comment: DevExpress has a bunch of Painting features, I will try to disable DevExpress, just to check if something changes, in that case I will try to find if something is different in the Options -> Editor -> Painting settings

Comment: This happened to me, bizarrely after removing ncrunch.  I visited the `Fonts and Colors` option, clicked `Use Defaults` and they magically all came back again.  FYI, I got "Unknown Error" when running the 'resetuserdata' answer above.