# Form Design Loading Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I opened VStudio2012 and created new project, it showed this error:

[image]

When I try to reopen new project, I see this error:

[image]

Properties of My PC;
OS : Win 7 SP1; VS version : VS2012 Ultimate; SQL ver.: SQL Server 2008 + 2012;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had deleted code before delete the object. So, before I deleted Button_1_Click() event in .cs file. But I should have deleted button1 and after delete Button_1_Click() event.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a similar issue has been resolved on another post please review the answer. Hope this helps

[Plain C# Editor in Visual Studio 2012 (No intellisense, no indentation, no code highlighting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988077/plain-c-sharp-editor-in-visual-studio-2012-no-intellisense-no-indentation-no)

Comment: ***

Thanks RawMx for your suggestion, but unfortunately, it doesn't
working.

***

Comment: Thanks my friend. I couldnt try this method. Because I didn't seen your post.