# Cannot find user keywords section in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

For visual studio 2012 . 
I can not find in
Tool / Options / font and colors / Display items / user keywords and many items for C#
where? anyone help me please

Answer (score 3):

Please see below. I checked in both copies of VS 2010 Pro and VS 2012 Professional and both has the same settings for User defined types (keywords) etc. Please see below screen snap.

[image]

Hope this helps.

You need to find **Developer Command Prompt for VS2012** and **Run it as Administrator**. You need to search for it if you are using Windows8 or typical path could be

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Visual Studio Tools
```

On any other versions of Windows, you can easily find it in your start menu's

```
Visual Studio 20xx > Visual Studio Tools > Visual Studio Command Prompt
```

and then just run **`devenv.exe /setup`** command. Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Random tip: "RGB for default enum/interface color in #VS2012 dark theme, luminosity adjusted to work with the classes color in the light theme is 668C92." (Red 102, Green 140, Blue 146) [source tweet](https://twitter.com/samharwell/status/302136911848427521)

Comment: missing my visual studio 2012. how to get this items?

Comment: Please see the edited answer above.

Comment: Also make sure that **Text Editor** is selected in the drop down list of **Show settings for:** on top of the dialog box. Please mark as answer if it does it for you. Thanks.

Comment: currently text editör is selected. but my settings is missing. maybe uninstall and install again :(

Comment: See the edited answer above. did you try running `devenv.exe /setup`? It should resolve the issue.

Comment: I get operation cannot be completed when running that