# Application Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, forms, windows-forms-designer

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2012. I have this message "The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed" after the next actions: file - create - project - Application Windows Forms. I do not do nothing else. I have already tried to repair VS, but it couldn't help.
Please, tell me what should I do to solve this problem. There is a code below:

Program.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
    {
       static class Program
       {
          /// <summary>
          /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
          /// </summary>
          [STAThread]
          static void Main()
          {
             Application.EnableVisualStyles();
             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
             Application.Run(new Form1());
          }
       }
    }
```

Form1.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
    {
       public partial class Form1: Form
       {
          public Form1()
          {
             InitializeComponent();
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your Visual Studio installation is corrupt.
The first answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988077/plain-c-sharp-editor-in-visual-studio-2012-no-intellisense-no-indentation-no)
may solve your issue.

The solution is, briefly:

1. Delete a value corresponding to the “Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.Interop” assembly from the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global\`. Note the `Interop` part because there is also `Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language` assembly, which must be in the GAC.
2. Start `VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt` and run `gacutil /u Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.Interop`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project and go to `Properties`, make sure target framework is set to `.NET 4.0` and not `.NET 4.0 Client Profile` or any other framework.