# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 cannot set breakpoint in c# file

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 installed, version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3.

When debugging a c# (.cs) file Visual Studio gives me the following message when I try to set a breakpoint:

> "A breakpoint could not be inserted at this location".

I get this message even when trying to set it on a line within a method.  But in a .vb file for a Visual Basic app, I can set a breakpoint.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions to resolve this or if I need to reinstall visual studio.

Thanks

Comment: Are you in `debug` profile?

Comment: Have you restarted VS? Is Intellisense working?

Comment: Yes.  I am in debug profile. I have restarted VS and intellisense is working.

Comment: What line are you inserting it on? You can't put a breakpoint on a declaration (unless it is being assigned to), for example.

Comment: In a test c# console app I have a line: t="aaa";  I get the same message when trying to set it at this line.

Comment: To fix this, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47030533/4528744

Comment: To fix this, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47030533/4528744

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution for this.  I had to do a repair on my Visual Studio 2012 instance through the control panel -> Programs and Features, right clicking on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012, and selecting change.  In the Visual Studio window I then selected repair.

As part of the repair process, I also had to download web deploy located here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4148 and point the visual studio repair process to the .msi file when it said it couldn't find the web deploy package and could not download it from the internet.

I also had to implement the fix indicated in the following stackoverflow question: [Plain C# Editor in Visual Studio 2012 (No intellisense, no indentation, no code highlighting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988077/plain-c-sharp-editor-in-visual-studio-2012-no-intellisense-no-indentation-no)

Now I am able to debug applications as expected.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe I'm too late for this question but here it goes anyway,

1. BUILD > Clean Solution
2. BUILD > Build Solution

Comment: Thankfully this did the job for me.

Answer (score 7):

I have encountered a similar issue and I resolved it by exiting Visual Studio and deleting the `.suo` file from my solution folder.

This file is recreated when you open the project again and it is not harmful to delete it.

The `.suo` is used for storing the layout of your solutions, the breakpoints you've set, the tabs you had open, etcetera.
I am not sure why this worked but my logic was that Visual Studio thought I was trying to place a breakpoint in a location different to where I was actually placing it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I exited visual studio and then deleted the .suo file.  But when I opened the solution again, it still gave me the same message when trying to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a try. Hope you find a solution that works for you.

Comment: @Kokodoko .suo is a hidden file. so you'll need to check that your file options to make sure they're bring displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, sheesh...for people as dumb as me, here's one more thing to consider:

You can put breakpoints on the curly braces at the start or close of a method, and you can put breakpoints on any line that is doing something (e.g. assigning a value or calling a method).  However, you can't put a breakpoint on a line that is only declaring a variable or otherwise "doing nothing."

E.g. I had a method:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeObject> GetList()
{
    int distance;
    var otherVar = SomeValue;
}
```

I was trying to put the breakpoint on the first line with `int distance;`, which is something that works fine in other IDEs, but that doesn't work in VS.  I had to go up to the brace or down to the next line with the assignment in order to get the breakpoint to set.

5 minutes of my life wasted, that I'll never get back, trying to debug a non-issue `;-p`

Answer (score 1):

VS 2017
I had this, I was missing an ; inside a for loop

Comment: I noticed the same too in VS 2017. Sometimes when I have compilation error (red squiggly lines), I'm unable to place any breakpoint too. But this happens very rarely though.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no instructions to execute on a line, VS refuses to set a breakpoint an offers no reason. EG

```
string str; //Cannot set breakpoint
string str = ""; //Can set breakpoint
```