# Visual Studio 2013 lost code formatting, C#

Tags: c#, formatting, visual-studio-2013

I've updated my Visual Studio to 2013 Professional, but in doing so I seem to have lost a lot of the code formatting.  I've gone into *Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors* and reset the defaults.  I've even gone *Tools - Options - Environment - Import and Export Settings and browsed to my 2012 settings folder*, but again I am missing out on a lot of code formatting.

Keywords are highlighted, but any classes etc are not.  Other people in my team have upgraded without any problems (I just used the default download installer)

Any help is much appreciated as currently I'm basically just using a glorified version of notepad to code with this below image

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to compile the code? it could be visual studio doesn't recognize your classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plain C# Editor in Visual Studio 2012 (No intellisense, no indentation, no code highlighting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988077/plain-c-sharp-editor-in-visual-studio-2012-no-intellisense-no-indentation-no)

Comment: Code compiles fine - I've tried this across multiple different solutions just to make sure and all build ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Productive Power Tools, *go to => Tools -> Options -> Productive Power Tools*. In main menu, *TURN OFF* the option: *Colorized Parameter* Help.

> Otherwise Go to tools in visual studio > Option>TextEditor>C#>See the option for anything you missed . (Am not sure , It's pretty,But it's my small idea only)

See this same discussions :[Plain C# Editor in Visual Studio 2012 (No intellisense, no indentation, no code highlighting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988077/plain-c-sharp-editor-in-visual-studio-2012-no-intellisense-no-indentation-no)

Comment: I'm not currently using these tools, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the link - I eventually managed to get this problem fixed using this line: Try running devenv /Resetuserdata in Command Prompt to reset all of your VS environment and customization settings.

Comment: @Wobble Having the same problem, but cannot seem to locate the command prompt. Where?

Answer (score 0):

Once in a while (each day) I have the same problem. Especially after changing project branch in git.

The simplest way to fix so far: file, close solution and then file, recent projects and solutions and reload your solution.