# Visual Studio 2012 (Windows 8.1) C# editor, Usertypes color

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, usertype

I've tried following the steps in the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988077/plain-c-sharp-editor-in-visual-studio-2012-no-intellisense-no-indentation-no) but I'm stuck on step two.

**I have the same issue as the question linked above. But the accepted answer did not work for me, as explained below.**

When I do the following:

> Start "VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" and run "gacutil /u
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.Interop".

I get this error:

> Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version
>   4.0.30319.17929 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> No assemblies found matching:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.In terop Number of
>   assemblies uninstalled = 0 Number of failures = 0

If I go to Fonts and Colors settings in Tools->Options, I do not have UserTypes available either.

Can anyone tell me what I can do? Can I add this library somehow?

Comment: Then the problem isn't the one described by the accepted answer to that question.

Comment: You haven't described what your problem is - are you getting no syntax highlighting, as per the linked question? If so, you should make this clear in your question - if not, you should make whatever your issue is obvious.

Comment: The problem is described in the question I linked to, but the accepted answer didn't work for me because the second step failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations.  That means that your machine was not infected by a beta version of Visual Studio.  Rather a notorious problem with VS Beta and RC editions, the uninstaller is always the last thing they get right.

What you are trying to do has *nothing* to do with the problem you are trying to solve.

You'll want to read [this feedback article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/795980/visual-studio-2012-premium-is-not-showing-the-class-user-types-color), posted by a VS user that also complained about missing User Type settings in the dialog.  No boo or bah back from the original poster of the article, sounds like `devenv /setup` took care of the problem.

Comment: I ran devenv /setup in the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012" and They're there now. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to give the bounty when I accepted the answer. Done now.

Answer (score 0):

delete Visual Studio and .Net framework where it's  update system and .Net framework